# Webform Composites, Variants and Computed Twig Elements

Tags: webforms, 9

The webform uses webform composites using the [webform_composite](https://drupal.org/project/webform_composite) module and a variant to show different fields on different reference nodes. Here's the form:

```
uuid: 70a21716-dfec-471a-a6e5-f70046bb8783
langcode: en
status: open
dependencies: {  }
weight: 0
open: null
close: null
uid: null
template: false
archive: false
id: ovc_ncvrw_nomination_scorecard
title: 'Nomination scorecard'
description: 'Nomination scorecard.'
categories: {  }
elements: |-
  ovc_ncvrw_award:
    '#type': webform_variant
    '#title': 'OVC NCVRW Award'
    '#variant': override
  factors:
    '#type': fieldset
    '#title': Factors
    factors_allied_professional_award:
      '#type': 'webform_composite:factors_allied_professional_award'
      '#title': 'Allied Professional Award'
      '#default_value':
        factor_one: ''
        rev_score_one: ''
        max_score_one: '25'
        factor_two: ''
        rev_score_two: ''
        max_score_two: '25'
        factor_three: ''
        rev_score_three: ''
        max_score_three: '25'
        factor_four: ''
        rev_score_four: ''
        max_score_four: '25'
    factors_award_for_first_responders:
      '#type': 'webform_composite:factors_award_for_first_responders'
      '#title': 'Award for First Responders'
      '#default_value':
        factor_one: ''
        rev_score_one: ''
        max_score_one: '25'
        factor_two: ''
        rev_score_two: ''
        max_score_two: '25'
        factor_three: ''
        rev_score_three: ''
        max_score_three: '25'
        factor_four: ''
        rev_score_four: ''
        max_score_four: '25'
      '#access': false
  calculation:
    '#type': fieldset
    '#title': Total
    factor_rev_score:
      '#type': webform_computed_twig
      '#title': "Reviewer's Score"
      '#title_display': inline
      '#template': |-
        {% set composite_data = data.factors_allied_professional_award %}
        {% set rev_score_one = composite_data.rev_score_one %}
        {% set rev_score_two = composite_data.rev_score_two %}
        {% set rev_score_three = composite_data.rev_score_three %}
        {% set rev_score_four = composite_data.rev_score_four %}
        {% if rev_score_one|length and rev_score_two|length and rev_score_three|length and rev_score_four|length %}
        {{ rev_score_one + rev_score_two + rev_score_three + rev_score_four }}{% else %}{% endif %}
      '#whitespace': spaceless
      '#store': true
      '#ajax': true
    factor_max_score:
      '#type': webform_computed_twig
      '#title': 'Max Score'
      '#title_display': inline
      '#template': |-
        {% set composite_data = data.factors_allied_professional_award %}
        {% set max_score_one = composite_data.max_score_one %}
        {% set max_score_two = composite_data.max_score_two %}
        {% set max_score_three = composite_data.max_score_three %}
        {% set max_score_four = composite_data.max_score_four %}
        {% if max_score_one|length and max_score_two|length and max_score_three|length and max_score_four|length %}
        {{ max_score_one + max_score_two + max_score_three + max_score_four }}{% endif %}
      '#whitespace': spaceless
      '#store': true
css: ''
javascript: ''
settings:
  ajax: false
  ajax_scroll_top: form
  ajax_progress_type: ''
  ajax_effect: ''
  ajax_speed: null
  page: false
  page_submit_path: ''
  page_confirm_path: ''
  page_theme_name: ''
  form_title: source_entity_webform
  form_submit_once: true
  form_open_message: ''
  form_close_message: ''
  form_exception_message: ''
  form_previous_submissions: true
  form_confidential: false
  form_confidential_message: ''
  form_disable_remote_addr: false
  form_convert_anonymous: false
  form_prepopulate: true
  form_prepopulate_source_entity: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_required: false
  form_prepopulate_source_entity_type: ''
  form_unsaved: false
  form_disable_back: false
  form_submit_back: false
  form_disable_autocomplete: false
  form_novalidate: false
  form_disable_inline_errors: false
  form_required: false
  form_autofocus: false
  form_details_toggle: false
  form_reset: false
  form_access_denied: default
  form_access_denied_title: ''
  form_access_denied_message: ''
  form_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  form_file_limit: ''
  form_attributes: {  }
  form_method: ''
  form_action: ''
  share: false
  share_node: false
  share_theme_name: ''
  share_title: true
  share_page_body_attributes: {  }
  submission_label: '[webform_submission:submitted-to] by [webform_submission:user:account-name]'
  submission_exception_message: ''
  submission_locked_message: ''
  submission_log: true
  submission_excluded_elements: {  }
  submission_exclude_empty: false
  submission_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  submission_views: {  }
  submission_views_replace: {  }
  submission_user_columns: {  }
  submission_user_duplicate: false
  submission_access_denied: default
  submission_access_denied_title: ''
  submission_access_denied_message: ''
  submission_access_denied_attributes: {  }
  previous_submission_message: ''
  previous_submissions_message: ''
  autofill: false
  autofill_message: ''
  autofill_excluded_elements: {  }
  wizard_progress_bar: true
  wizard_progress_pages: false
  wizard_progress_percentage: false
  wizard_progress_link: false
  wizard_progress_states: false
  wizard_start_label: ''
  wizard_preview_link: false
  wizard_confirmation: true
  wizard_confirmation_label: ''
  wizard_auto_forward: true
  wizard_auto_forward_hide_next_button: false
  wizard_keyboard: true
  wizard_track: ''
  wizard_prev_button_label: ''
  wizard_next_button_label: ''
  wizard_toggle: false
  wizard_toggle_show_label: ''
  wizard_toggle_hide_label: ''
  wizard_page_type: container
  wizard_page_title_tag: h2
  preview: 0
  preview_label: ''
  preview_title: ''
  preview_message: ''
  preview_attributes: {  }
  preview_excluded_elements: {  }
  preview_exclude_empty: true
  preview_exclude_empty_checkbox: false
  draft: authenticated
  draft_multiple: true
  draft_auto_save: true
  draft_saved_message: |-
    Submission saved. You may return to this form later and it will restore the current values.<br />
    <br />
    Please note: your draft submission will be deleted in 3 days.
  draft_loaded_message: ''
  draft_pending_single_message: ''
  draft_pending_multiple_message: ''
  confirmation_type: url_message
  confirmation_url: '[current-user:url]'
  confirmation_title: ''
  confirmation_message: |-
    <p>Thank you, the form has been submitted.<br />
    <br />
    Click <strong>Submissions</strong> to review your submission.</p>
  confirmation_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_back: true
  confirmation_back_label: 'Back to form'
  confirmation_back_attributes: {  }
  confirmation_exclude_query: true
  confirmation_exclude_token: true
  confirmation_update: false
  limit_total: null
  limit_total_interval: null
  limit_total_message: ''
  limit_total_unique: false
  limit_user: 5
  limit_user_interval: 60
  limit_user_message: ''
  limit_user_unique: false
  entity_limit_total: null
  entity_limit_total_interval: null
  entity_limit_user: 5
  entity_limit_user_interval: 60
  purge: draft
  purge_days: 3
  results_disabled: false
  results_disabled_ignore: false
  results_customize: false
  token_view: false
  token_update: false
  token_delete: false
  serial_disabled: false
access: {  }
handlers: {  }
variants:
  allied_professional_award:
    id: override
    variant_id: allied_professional_award
    element_key: ovc_ncvrw_award
    label: 'Allied Professional Award'
    notes: ''
    status: true
    weight: -50
    settings:
      debug: false
      settings: {  }
      elements: ''
      handlers: {  }
  award_for_first_responders:
    id: override
    variant_id: award_for_first_responders
    element_key: ovc_ncvrw_award
    label: 'Award for First Responders'
    notes: ''
    status: true
    weight: -49
    settings:
      debug: false
      settings: {  }
      elements: "ovc_ncvrw_award:\r\n  '#type': webform_variant\r\n  '#title': 'OVC NCVRW Award'\r\n  '#variant': override\r\nfactors:\r\n  '#type': fieldset\r\n  '#title': Factors\r\nfactors_allied_professional_award:\r\n  '#type': 'webform_composite:factors_allied_professional_award'\r\n  '#title': 'Allied Professional Award'\r\n  '#default_value':\r\n    factor_one: ''\r\n    rev_score_one: ''\r\n    max_score_one: '25'\r\n    factor_two: ''\r\n    rev_score_two: ''\r\n    max_score_two: '25'\r\n    factor_three: ''\r\n    rev_score_three: ''\r\n    max_score_three: '25'\r\n    factor_four: ''\r\n    rev_score_four: ''\r\n    max_score_four: '25'\r\n  '#access': false\r\nfactors_award_for_first_responders:\r\n  '#type': 'webform_composite:factors_award_for_first_responders'\r\n  '#title': 'Award for First Responders'\r\n  '#default_value':\r\n    factor_one: ''\r\n    rev_score_one: ''\r\n    max_score_one: '25'\r\n    factor_two: ''\r\n    rev_score_two: ''\r\n    max_score_two: '25'\r\n    factor_three: ''\r\n    rev_score_three: ''\r\n    max_score_three: '25'\r\n    factor_four: ''\r\n    rev_score_four: ''\r\n    max_score_four: '25'\r\n  '#access': true\r\ncalculation:\r\n  '#type': fieldset\r\n  '#title': Total\r\nfactor_rev_score:\r\n  '#type': webform_computed_twig\r\n  '#title': \"Reviewer's Score\"\r\n  '#title_display': inline\r\n  '#template': |-\r\n    {% set composite_data = data.factors_award_for_first_responders %}\r\n    {% set rev_score_one = composite_data.rev_score_one %}\r\n    {% set rev_score_two = composite_data.rev_score_two %}\r\n    {% set rev_score_three = composite_data.rev_score_three %}\r\n    {% set rev_score_four = composite_data.rev_score_four %}\r\n    {% if rev_score_one|length and rev_score_two|length and rev_score_three|length and rev_score_four|length %}\r\n    {{ rev_score_one + rev_score_two + rev_score_three + rev_score_four }}{% else %}{% endif %}\r\n  '#whitespace': spaceless\r\n  '#store': true\r\n  '#ajax': true\r\nfactor_max_score:\r\n  '#type': webform_computed_twig\r\n  '#title': 'Max Score'\r\n  '#title_display': inline\r\n  '#template': |-\r\n    {% set composite_data = data.factors_award_for_first_responders %}\r\n    {% set max_score_one = composite_data.max_score_one %}\r\n    {% set max_score_two = composite_data.max_score_two %}\r\n    {% set max_score_three = composite_data.max_score_three %}\r\n    {% set max_score_four = composite_data.max_score_four %}\r\n    {% if max_score_one|length and max_score_two|length and max_score_three|length and max_score_four|length %}\r\n    {{ max_score_one + max_score_two + max_score_three + max_score_four }}{% endif %}\r\n  '#whitespace': spaceless\r\n  '#store': true"
      handlers: {  }
```

Here are the composites:

```
id: factors_allied_professional_award
uuid: f3acf1c1-10fb-43d0-b28e-280d52890323
status: true
label: 'Factors: Allied Professional Award'
elements: |
  factor_one:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Allied Professional Award Factor one.'
  rev_score_one:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_one:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_two:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Allied Professional Award Factor two.'
  rev_score_two:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_two:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_three:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Allied Professional Award Factor three.'
  rev_score_three:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_three:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_four:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Allied Professional Award Factor four.'
  rev_score_four:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_four:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
description: 'Add factors for the Allied Professional Award to this form.'
langcode: en
dependencies: {  }
```

and

```
id: factors_award_for_first_responders
uuid: dd9f4c4a-769e-4672-8a9d-a85f6faf67aa
status: true
label: 'Factors: Award for First Responders'
elements: |
  factor_one:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Award for First Responders Factor one.'
  rev_score_one:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_one:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_two:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Award for First Responders Factor two.'
  rev_score_two:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_two:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_three:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Award for First Responders Factor three.'
  rev_score_three:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_three:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
  factor_four:
    '#type': textarea
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Sample Factor: Describe Award for First Responders Factor four.'
  rev_score_four:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Rev. Score'
  max_score_four:
    '#type': number
    '#required': true
    '#title': 'Max Score'
    '#readonly': true
description: 'Add factors for the Award for First Responders to this form.'
langcode: en
dependencies: {  }
```

Create a reference for each Variant. Call the first reference *Allied Professional Award*; the second, *Award for First Responders*. Submit the reference *Allied Professional Award*, and factor_rev_score is populated in both Edit and View in its result. Submit the reference for the variant, *Award for First Responders*, and factor_rev_score is populated in Edit result only. It's empty on View.

The problem is when I go to make a results view, Reviewer's score is empty for the variant, same as it is on the webform result view tab.

I've tried using webform's built in composite element and gotten the same result. So it's not the webform composite module. I think the twig template may be the problem. The twig template works in the build, the non-variant version.

```
{% set composite_data = data.factors_allied_professional_award %}
{% set rev_score_one = composite_data.rev_score_one %}
{% set rev_score_two = composite_data.rev_score_two %}
{% set rev_score_three = composite_data.rev_score_three %}
{% set rev_score_four = composite_data.rev_score_four %}
{% if rev_score_one|length and rev_score_two|length and rev_score_three|length and rev_score_four|length %}
{{ rev_score_one + rev_score_two + rev_score_three + rev_score_four }}{% else %}{% endif %}
```

In the variant, I'm overriding the twig template with

```
{% set composite_data = data.factors_award_for_first_responders %}
{% set rev_score_one = composite_data.rev_score_one %}
{% set rev_score_two = composite_data.rev_score_two %}
{% set rev_score_three = composite_data.rev_score_three %}
{% set rev_score_four = composite_data.rev_score_four %}
{% if rev_score_one|length and rev_score_two|length and rev_score_three|length and rev_score_four|length %}
{{ rev_score_one + rev_score_two + rev_score_three + rev_score_four }}{% else %}{% endif %}
```

I can build the result view around this missing View element by excluding from display rev_score_one through rev_score_four and then rewriting an output field. But since mysql has limits on how many tables can be queried at one time, eventually that bad smelling solution will fail.

Why is the variant result View empty when the Edit is not?